# store snapshots on server

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://www.google.com/");

File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

Using this code to take snapshots using selenium web-driver. This code only stores snaphots locally on my PC. If i want to run it automatically from Jenkins, is there any way to store that snapshots somewhere else so that if anyone runs it either though Jenkins or locally from their PC, they don't have to change the link(("c:\tmp\screenshot.png") every time.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the location of the output file something that it controlled by a setting - either a command-line argument to the tool running this code (if you can modify that), or an environment variable that you can read from your section of code above. You could also have a default location that always exists and should be writable like the user's home directory, rather than an absolute path to c:\tmp.

In jenkins, I would have a step (in an ant script, shell script, or whatnot) create a folder called "screenshots" below $WORKSPACE, and then tell the tool that's going to run your code about that location by one of the methods suggested above. This will also be handy if you want to make the screenshots part of the job's output.

Also, unless you really only ever need the latest file (or have downstream code consuming the screenshot and expecting a specific name), I would introduce a timestamp or some other variable file-naming for the png in the code above, e.g. screenshot-2014-05-16_12-15-37.png, so that if you run the tool twice it doesn't just overwrite the file that was there before.

hth